# Scripts doesn't work in angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I made a dashboard with Angular.
I included all my scripts in my index.html, but every time I click a link, only the html and css are executed.

The Javascripts' actions are not executed such as graphs that i implemented.

I have to reload the page for everything to work normally.

That is my index.html source

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <!-- Bootstrap Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FontAwesome Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Morris Chart Styles-->
    <link href="assets/js/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Google Fonts-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/Lightweight-Chart/cssCharts.css">

</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris Chart Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/morris/morris.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/Lightweight-Chart/jquery.chart.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom-scripts.js"></script>




    <!-- Tabs -->
    <!-- jQuery Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris Chart Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/morris/morris.js"></script>


    <script src="assets/js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/Lightweight-Chart/jquery.chart.js"></script>
    <!-- DATA TABLE SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
    <!--Pizza-->
    <script src="assets/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/pizza.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your Image seems broken

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Case angular-cli and latest version, copy path of your scripts in angular-cli.json.

Ex.:

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"
 ],
```